# How to update the selected rows in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i was trying to update the data from the selected row on datagridview but when i clicked the Update button all the data even the not selected rows are edited..

here is my code:

```
connect.Open()
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value = TextBox8.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value = TextBox1.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value = TextBox2.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value = TextBox3.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value = TextBox4.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value = TextBox5.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(7).Value = TextBox6.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(8).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(9).Value = TextBox9.Text

        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
        cmd.CommandText = "update tbl_book_info set Title = '" & TextBox1.Text & "',Author = '" & TextBox2.Text & "',Copyright = '" & TextBox3.Text & "',Publisher = '" & TextBox4.Text & "',Place = '" & TextBox5.Text & "',Copies = '" & TextBox6.Text & "',Subject = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "',ClassNo = '" & TextBox8.Text & "',Registered = '" & TextBox9.Text & "',Time = '" & TextBox10.Text & "',Date = '" & TextBox11.Text & "' where ISBN = ISBN "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Data Saved!")
        EDIT.Text = "Edit"

        data = New DataTable()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = data

        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
        da.Fill(data)
```

please help.. I'm a beginner in vb.net

Comment: Again, always use SQL Parameters. There are many opportunities for that code to fail. Try using a title like `A Hobbit's Tale` or an author like `O'Henry` -  your code will crash.  You also appear to be passing what ought to be numeric data - like copies - as text.  You should also know that data can be edited in the DGV without taking it out, and using a DataAdapter and DataTable properly, all you need is `myDt.Update(myBooksDT)`

Comment: @ Plutonix - It appears though the users are editing data through textboxes and the code is creating a datagridview from the textboxes. Not sure if you caught that.

Comment: Yes I did.  For an edit (UPDATE), it means that elsewhere the data had to move the other way. For a new row, the user can use the automatic thing when AllowUSerToAddRows is true or add  a row via code.